# OpenCL how to control number of processors to use

Tags: opencl

I want to control the number of GPU cores to test the speedup. How can I do that in OpenCL? I realize I can control group size to control synchronization, but I'm confused since group size can be more than hundred, which is far larger than the number of GPU cores.

Comment: Use device fission (OpenCL >= 1.2).

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae please write it as an answer to wipe the question from the unanswered tab.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called *device fission*. It is an extension in OpenCL 1.1 and in the core specification from OpenCL 1.2 onwards.

To give you a starting point, you will need to use [`clCreateSubDevices`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubDevices.html). For example, to restrict your kernel to run on only one compute unit, you may pass `properties` as such:

```
{
    CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS, 
    1, // Use only one compute unit
    CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS_LIST_END
}
```

This tells the driver to create one sub-device composed of one compute unit. You may then run your kernel on that sub-device, which will be scheduled on one compute unit only.

Comment: By default, all the cores will be used?

Comment: If you run your kernel on a *physical* device (the ones returned by `clGetDevices`), then yes, all compute units will be used (the term "core" has an ambiguous meaning). If you run your kernel on a *logical* device (a sub-device), then only the number of compute units you've specified will be used.

Comment: When i used this on a nbody algorithm on fx8150 to select only 7-cores instead of 8, then performance went up by %50 - %70, maybe using all cores for opencl doesnt let any other thread a chance to run .

Comment: I don't think so, probably the new `global size / cores` gave a better default workgroup size than with the old value of cores (8). More cores is always better performance.

Comment: I'm still stuck at getting it work. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526963/opencl-create-subdevices-cl-device-partition-failed