# OpenCL create subdevices CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED

Tags: opencl

I'm stuck at getting `clCreateSubDevices` working, where `CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED` is always returned and I have no clue to solve this problem. I'm trying to create a subdevice with one core only. Here is the code, do you see anything wrong with it? Thanks!

Here are the function signatures:
[clCreateSubDevices](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubDevices.html), [clGetPlatformIDs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html), [clGetDeviceIDs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html)

```
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,
                     &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

if (device_id == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device id!");
    return 1;
}

const cl_device_partition_property properties[3] = {
    CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS,
    1, // Use only one compute unit
    CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS_LIST_END
};

cl_device_id subdevice_id;
cl_int error = clCreateSubDevices(device_id, properties, 1, &subdevice_id, NULL);
if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create sub device %d!\n", error);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED` means the device cannot be further partitioned. On what device are you working?

Comment: Mac OS Intel Iris. Is it the graphics card that caused the problem?

Comment: only cpu can be fissioned for now. gpu are unable. maybe in the future.